# Return list with n'th values of a list of lists - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first question here. I just started coding in Python, and trying to finish an assignment for my study in Python (it is actually supposed to be made in STATA but I want to learn Python).

So I want to do the following (note that the final_list consists of 15000 rows, this is just a small example):

```
final_list = [[2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 11.0, 50612.0, 0.38875884563387036, 0.5924978852272034, 8.400468826293945, 516.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2003.0], [2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 11.0, 50612.0, 0.38875884563387036, 0.5924978852272034, 8.400468826293945, 517.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2003.0], [2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 11.0, 50612.0, 0.38875884563387036, 0.5924978852272034, 8.400468826293945, 518.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2003.0]
```

to

```
treshold = [11.0, 11.0, 11.0]
```

Now what I've tried is this:

```
treshold = []
for sublist in final_list:
    treshold_lst = sublist[3]
    treshold.append(treshold_lst)
print(treshold)
```

I receive the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any error in your code https://repl.it/repls/OilyResponsibleBaboon

Comment: are you sure that `final_list` looks like that?

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: The `final_list` you've posted now is invalid. The problem obviously lies with that list, not with the logic you've posted.

Comment: Have you just changed your code?

Comment: I just changed the final_list to the exact values.

Comment: @StephenTheunissen The problem clearly lies in another sublist. Running your code with this list is successful. If you're getting an `IndexError` because you have an "index out of range", this means the index you're using is out of range of one of the sublists. Try seeing what your shortest sublist is (`min(final_list, key=len)`).

Comment: Your list have a problem, you didn't close the first bracket

Answer (score 2):

Try `list comprehension`:

```
final_list = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,3,4,6]]
treshold = [sub[-1] for sub in final_list]
```